# What does holding a resource is a class invariante mean in RAII?

Tags: c++, raii, invariants

#### What does mean holding a resource is a class invariante in RAII?

On the [RAII's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) it does states:

> In RAII, holding a resource is a class invariant, and is tied to object lifetime: resource allocation (acquisition) is done during object creation (specifically initialization), by the constructor, while resource deallocation (release) is done during object destruction (specifically finalization), by the destructor.

On a `D language` example, we can easily understand what does a `Class Invariant` means:

```
class Date {
  int day;
  int hour;

  invariant() {
    assert(1 <= day && day <= 31);
    assert(0 <= hour && hour < 24);
  }
}
```

It is a constraint referring to what can class field to hold on to be considered on a valid state. However what does it has to mean with holding a resource? Does it mean the resource is mine and will be mine from its construction by the constructor, until its destruction by de destrutor?

Comment: For anyone else, I found out this link explaining RAII better: http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/resource-acquisition-is-initialisation-raii-explained/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Does it mean the resource is mine and will be mine from its construction by the constructor, until its destruction by de destrutor

In a correctly design program this is the case but the concept of ownership is not enforced in C++.

It is easy to "shoot yourself in the foot" and give the resource to some other object. For example, when the resource is a pointer, you can accidentally share it between objects, like this:

```
struct A
{
    int some_variable;
};

struct A_holder
{
    A* ptr;
    A_holder()
    {
        ptr = new A();
    }
    ~A_holder()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{

    {
        A_holder a_holder;
        auto another_A_holder = a_holder;
    }
   //error because delete is called twice:
   //first on A_holder's pointer and a second time on another_A_holder's pointer
    return 0;
}
```

See https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero for the rule of zero

Comment: worth adding `delete`ing the copy constructor and assignment operator as a simple defense against this

Comment: @user4581301 Yep, my favorite way is to inherit from boost::noncopyable

Comment: it is enforceable if you are following [rule of five / rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). change `ptr` to `unique_ptr`, will fix the problem.

Comment: @BryanChen Yes, but that isn't the same thing as the language demanding it. Think of "borrowing" in rust.

Comment: But your code standard / peer review can enforce it. Especially when in a code base where smart pointer are used everywhere, a raw pointer is very catchy.

Comment: So, to use RAII on C++ I must to delete the copy constructor and the assignment operator, never give my resources to anyone else? Therefore the Rule of Three and the Rule of Five became the Rule of 2 and the Rule of 4?

Comment: @addons_zz You want the rule of zero. Most things shouldn't own resources. Here is a link https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero

Comment: Then I only use the Rule of 3/5 when I am not using the RAII due resource holding.

Comment: @Mikhail: "*Most things shouldn't own resources.*" Better to say that most things shouldn't *directly* own resources.

Comment: @addons_zz You should only use the rule of 3/5 when your writing a an exceptionally special and rare class that will hold on to a resource, directly. For most programs this kind of class is already implemented in the from of things like std::vector<>.